# Combine datetime from separate date and time part (miliseconds, bigint) using Linq to Entity (EF Core)

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I want to check two dates overlapping but instead of datetime the DB table uses **date **and **bigint** so I need to combine them into datetime in C# code:

Table columns:
StartDate: date (null)
EndDate: date (null)
AvailableFromMs: bigint (null)
AvailableToMs: bigint (null)
[table-columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yquEm.png)

TEntity:

```
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? AvailableFromMs { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? AvailableToMs { get; set; }
```

[db-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4U7s.png)

Querying:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> query = <repository_to_query_from>...

DateTime routeStart = DateTime.Now;

 List<TEntity> overlapping = query
                 .Where(r => routeStart <= ((DateTime)(object)r.EndDate.Value).AddSeconds(r.AvailableToMs == null ? 0.0 : r.AvailableToMs.Value.Milliseconds / 1000.0))
                  .ToList();
```

(Note: I know that this is just part of the condition, I will update that when EF generates correct SQL)
SQL generated by EF Core looks like this:

```
WHERE...
  (@__routeStart_1 <= DATEADD(second, CAST(CASE
 WHEN [r].[AvailableToMs] IS NULL THEN 0.0E0
 ELSE CAST(DATEPART(millisecond, [r].[AvailableToMs]) AS float) / 1000.0E0
 END AS int), CAST([r].[EndDate] AS datetime2)))
```

But running this query throws:
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

This is because of the AvailableToMs  type: C# code divides it first by 1000 but EF generates that /1000.0E0 after the CAST() is performed and I want to do the division first, then do casting.

How can I force EF to do that?

Comment: If you're gonna throw the fractional part away by using an int, why not just datepart(second,....) without the division?

Comment: What do you mean? AvailableToMs is saved as bigint, e.g. 86340000 ms => 86,340 Seconds = 23 Hours : 59 Minutes : 0 Seconds I need to somehow lower this number to fit to DATEPART(). I tried the .AddMilliseconds(r.AvailableToMs == null ? 0.0 : r.AvailableToMs.Value.Milliseconds / 1000.0)  that generates CAST(DATEPART(millisecond, [r].[AvailableToMs]) AS float) / 1000.0E0 but with the same error message

Comment: Why properties are TimeSpan? Maybe better to store in `long`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all comments and ideas.

I ended with removing that TimeSpan dependency completely and just use long value to remove the DATEPART() from generated SQL:

```
.Where(r => routeStart <= ((DateTime)(object)r.EndDate.Value)
   .AddMilliseconds(r.AvailableToMs == null ? 0 : (long)(object)(r.AvailableToMs.Value))
```

Generated SQL is:

```
...WHERE 
  ((@__routeStart_1 <= DATEADD(millisecond, CAST(CAST(CASE
    WHEN [r].[AvailableToMs] IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS bigint)
    ELSE CAST([r].[AvailableToMs] AS bigint)
END AS float) AS int), CAST([r].[EndDate] AS datetime2)))
```

Some comments:

> These (object) castings look suspicious, but they are necessary:
>
> 1. EndDate is [db]date that does not have a time part. Without time calling AddMilliseconds() fails as LinqToEntity cannot
>    translate the expression correctly (requires [db]datetime not
>    [db]date)
> 2. AvailableToMs is [db]bigint and cannot be used directly (as TimeSpan) because the expression is translated as
>    DATEPART(millisecond, [r].[AvailableToMs]) AS bigint)
>    As DATEPART() is unable to handle bigint causing 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type
>    datetime.' SQL error (not an exception)

Some related links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities